# Check duplicate before inserting data in access database using asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net

I tried the mention below query to stop duplicate before inserting data. It works fine with SQL database but its not working with access database. I want the same query to stop duplicate before inserting data to my access database. waiting for positive response. Thanks

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM dbo.Product
                WHERE email = @email)
   INSERT INTO dbo.Product(list of columns)
   VALUES (list of values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases (SQL Server and MS Access) you should create a proper UNIQUE INDEX on the email column of the Product table.

For MS Access: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/prevent-entry-of-duplicate-values-mdb-HP005187564.aspx

For SQL Server: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189280.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I got your point. I have applied the primry key to the email column and used the try catach to prevent the Exception error.